# Symfony2 service loading

Tags: symfony, factory

I am currently designing an application in Symfony2 and had a question around when services are instantiated. Basically, are all services instantiated when the container is configured in the application load cycle or at the point when the service is requested from the container?

I understand you can flag services to be lazy loaded through the proxy manager but I just wanted to know what happens by default.

To add some context, I want to create a factory method that returns different services and am unsure whether to define the services in the service config and fetch them from the container when requested or simply instantiate them in the factory itself.

If Symfony loads all the services when the container is loaded then that's a lot of excessive overheard for what I'm trying to do. Also I'd rather not define concrete classes in the factory method.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Services are only created when requested from the container.  The lazy load is a different concept.  It comes into play when a services has other services injected into it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.